# How to change the widget for a computed field on a Django Admin model form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-widget

For a Django Admin model form, if you display a calculated field, is there a way to also specify the widget the form should used to display that field? I cannot seem to find any mention of this. All the examples I have found describe how to override a standard (i.e., non-calculated) field's widget.

Comment: Watching on with the same question. I've tried overriding the form, but because the computed field isn't on the model itself, the field isn't present on the form.